# I can't log in to my Mac, even though I can ssh into it

Tags: macos, networking, mac, ssh

**Our Mac is on a network where most users log in via ActiveDirectory, that may be related**

I am able to ssh from my machine to my MacMini (which is a build server for our iOS Developers), via `ssh matt@builtbot.local`  It accepts my login just fine, and I'm able to navigate around via the command line.

If I sit down at that machine and try to log in to OSX, it rejects my password.

What gives?

Until a week ago, I was always able to log in without issue.

Comment: Check for the input source on the upper right corner. Is it set to U.S. / whatever your English keyboard layout is? Also, it's a really stupid shot, but check for snappy keys, perhaps try another keyboard? (not even mentioning the Caps Lock because it shows the indicator in the password field)

Comment: Try changing your password to an other one through ssh using `passwd` command and try to log in again with a new one.

Comment: @IOXenus -- this fixed it! Thank you so much.  If you re-post this as the answer I'll choose it as 'accepted'

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is a simple fix, I hope. So when you sit down to your computer to try to log in and it doesn't let you, boot with holding cmd-r then go to terminal and use the command "resetpassword" just type that and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Change your password to an other one through ssh using `passwd` command and try to log in again with a new one.

But I don't have a clue as for what was the problem. :(